# Word count using map reduce on Seq[String]

Tags: scala

I have a `Seq` which contains randomly generated words.

I want to calculate the occurrence count of each word using map reduce.

Now, I have been able to map the words against a value 1 and grouped them together by words.

```
val mapValues = ourWords.map(word => (word, 1))
val groupedData = mapValues.groupBy(_._1)
```

However, I am not sure how to use the `reduce` function on `groupedData` to get the count.

I tried this -

```
groupedData.reduce((x, y) => x._2.reduce((x, y) => x._2) + y._2.reduce((l, r) => l._2))
```

but it's riddled with errors.

Comment: If you are in `2.13` you can just call `groupMapReduce` - If not, you want to call `reduce` on each group so you would use something like `mapValues` first.

Comment: `ourWords.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).toMap`